# Best tools for keeping a FreeBSD 7.x system up to date?

Tags: security, freebsd, update

I have had on-and-off contact with FreeBSD for 15 years, but I haven't maintained a FreeBSD system since 4.x. Now I need to install and maintain a couple of 7.x systems; first for development, then an Internet-facing server.

Looking through the FreeBSD Handbook (updating/upgrading) it seems that 'freebsd-update' is the preferred approach to keep the OS up to date, but there are multiple methods for managing the [ports tree and installed ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports-using.html).

The Handbook describes CVSup and Portsnap for keeping the ports tree up to date.  What do you recommend, and why (advantages/disadvantages)?

The Handbook also describes Portupgrade, Portmanager and Portmaster for keeping installed ports up to date.  What do you recommend, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [portaudit](http://www.freshports.org/security/portaudit/) to make security
  audit of installed ports
- [Subscribe](http://www.freebsd.org/security/advisories.rdf) via Google Reader or
  something similar to [FreeBSD
  Security](http://www.freebsd.org/security/)

Just remember - don't touch if it works. So, unless system hasn't got any vulnerabilities, let it be. If it has - update it to the latest release/patchlevel or update port with recursive rebuilding of dependencies.

Of course careful reading of `/usr/src/UPDATING` and `/usr/ports/UPDATING` is a **MUST**.

PS. Tools you'll use are doesn't really matter i think. I prefer:

- svn for OS source code management
- portsnap for ports tree
- portmaster/portupgrade port upgrading

Answer (score 2):

`freebsd-update` for OS updates

`portsnap` for ports sync

`portupgrade` for building from ports

`pkg_add -r` for grabbing binary packages, usually more reliable, but a little behind 
building from source using ports

`make buildworld/buildkernel/mergemaster` for the big version upgrades

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there seems to be lots of different ways and I wrestled with choosing a good one years ago. I like the author of freebsd-update and portsnap. They are dead simple to use and I throw them in a periodic script to run daily/weekly. They do for the most part binary updates. One thing though is that freebsd-update at least only tracks a certain release for so long. For example my file server that I have had for years and years is now not supported anymore. I resort to upgrading via source if I have the time and/or I need to do something that freebsd-update doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

I use `portsnap` to keep my ports tree up to date. I use this over `cvsup` as it appears to be a faster download. I have no evidence to back this up, though

As per SaveTheRbtz, use `portaudit` and read the output of your cron e-mails

Read `/usr/ports/UPDATING` prior to updating any ports for any important news

`portversion -L =` to see any ports that require updating

The handbook does describe the use of pretty much all the tool options available to you, it's really a matter of picking what suits your requirements